# Why this set is an algebra

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

My question is, how can I form the empty $\emptyset $ set with finite sets unions as in (9.1)?

Comment: Take $b \le a$.

Comment: The empty union is a finite union.

Comment: why? this is not one of the sets of definition (9.1)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to make the empty set.

One way is as the interval $(1,0]$, which is empty and of the given form.

The other is as the empty union: $$\bigcup_{I\in\varnothing}I$$This is a finite union, all the sets in the union are of the given form (maybe it's easier to think of as "it doesn't include any sets *not* of the given form"), and it equals the empty set.

Comment: The set: $[0,1)$ is not empty it is formally defined as $\{x\in mathbb R|0\leq 2\}, which has the infinite set of \mathbb R numbers from 0 to one in it. I don't understand how you are defining "no set"? What does it mean for a set to be a no set? I think you meant the infinite intersection of mutually disjoint sets is the finite empty set.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost It's not $[0,1)$ it's $(1,0]$, defined as $\{x\in\Bbb R\mid 1<x\leq0\}$. That's quite empty. And I didn't say "no set". I said "no sets". As in $\bigcup_{I\in\varnothing}I$. That's a finite union of sets on the given form, and it's empty.

Comment: @BertrandWittgenstein'sGhost The set mentioned in the post is $(1,0]$ which is not the same thing as the set $[0,1)$.  The set $(1,0]$ is the set $\{x\in\Bbb R~:~1<x\leq 0\}$ just like how $[0,1)$ is the set $\{x\in\Bbb R~:~0\leq x<1\}$.  The order from left to right is important here and cannot be ignored.  As for the empty union, it is the empty set just like how the empty product is the multiplicative identity and the empty sum is the additive identity.  [See empty sum on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum).

Comment: I am sorry, I misread the set. You are correct. I will upvote your comment and post

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, you are right. I misread the set. I probably skimmed over it, and didn't realize what was actually witten. I will upvote your comment.